# how could I achieve something like np.where(df[varaible] in ['value1','value2'])

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, series, categorical-data

Hi I want to change one categorical variable's value to `other` in the condition like `['value1','value2']`

Here is my code:

```
random_sample['NAME_INCOME_TYPE_ind'] = np.where(random_sample['NAME_INCOME_TYPE'] in ['Maternity leave', 'Student']), 'Other')
```

I tried adding `.any()` in different position of this line of code, but it still does not resolve the error.
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to check where the condition is satisfied:

```
l = ('|').join(['Maternity leave', 'Student'])
m = random_sample['NAME_INCOME_TYPE'].str.contains(l)
```

You could also generate `m` using [`.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
random_sample['NAME_INCOME_TYPE'].isin(['Maternity leave', 'Student'])
```

And then use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). However, note that you cannot only specify one of the two values from which to choose depending on the condition, you have to specify both `x` and `y`. For your case you could use  `df['NAME_INCOME_TYPE']` and `other` as `x` and `y`:

```
random_sample['NAME_INCOME_TYPE_ind'] = np.where(m, 
                                                'Other',
                                                random_sample['NAME_INCOME_TYPE'])
```

Test on an example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'NAME_INCOME_TYPE':['word1','word2','Student']})

l = ('|').join(['Maternity leave', 'Student'])
m = random_sample['NAME_INCOME_TYPE'].str.contains(l)
df['NAME_INCOME_TYPE_ind'] = np.where(m, 'Other', df['NAME_INCOME_TYPE'])

       NAME_INCOME_TYPE NAME_INCOME_TYPE_ind
0            word1                word1
1            word2                word2
2          Student                Other
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Use [Categorical Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) for categorical variables

When dealing with categoricals, you can **replace categories** with another rather than replacing strings. This has memory and performance benefits, as internally Pandas uses factorisation for categorical data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'NAME_INCOME_TYPE': ['Employed', 'Maternity leave',
                                        'Benefits', 'Student']})

# turn object series to categorical
label_col = 'NAME_INCOME_TYPE'
df[label_col] = df[label_col].astype('category')

# define others
others = ['Maternity leave', 'Student']
others_label = 'Other'

# add new category and replace existing categories
df[label_col] = df[label_col].cat.add_categories([others_label])
df[label_col] = df[label_col].replace(others, others_label)

print(df)

  NAME_INCOME_TYPE
0         Employed
1            Other
2         Benefits
3            Other
```

You can also write this more succinctly using method chaining:

```
# define others
others, others_label = ['Maternity leave', 'Student'], 'Other'

# turn to categorical, add category, then replace
df['NAME_INCOME_TYPE'] = df['NAME_INCOME_TYPE'].astype('category')\
                                               .cat.add_categories([others_label])\
                                               .replace(others, others_label)
```